# Get Google Maps Geocoding JSON from Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps, express

I've been teaching myself Node.js and Express, and I am trying to return the JSON result from a Google Maps Geocoding API request. I have gotten it to to work using the `require` module, BUT I am trying to figure out what I did wrong in Express so I have learned it:

**Express Attempt: htmlController.js**

```
// FYI: This controller gets called from an app.js file where express() and 
// the mapsAPI is passed as arguments.

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

module.exports = function(app, mapsAPI){
app.post('/maps', urlencodedParser, function(req,results){
   var lat;
   var long;
   var add = req.body.add;
     app.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + add + '&key=' + mapsAPI, function(req,res){
        lat = res.results.geometry.northeast.lat;
        long = res.results.geometry.northeast.long;
        console.log(lat); // no output
        console.log(lat); // no output
  }, function(){
        console.log(lat); // no output
        console.log(long); // no output
  });
  results.send("Thanks!");
});
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to log it in different code blocks, but any log inside the API request is not getting shown to the console.

**Working Request using the `require` Module:**

```
app.post('/maps', urlencodedParser, function(req,results){
  var add = req.body.add;
  request({
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + add + '&key=' + mapsAPI,
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body) // Print the json response
    }
  });
  results.send("Thanks!");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get data from maps api by using `app.get()`

```
app.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + add + '&key=' + mapsAPI, function(req,res){}
```

But `app.get()` function is used for your app route only, not to fetch remote data. same for `router.get()`

```
// app.get(appRoute, middlewareORhandler)
app.get('/myOwnApp/api/users/12/', function(res,res,next)){
    // your code here
    res.status(200).send("return your response here");
}
```

to make a remote request you can use built-in `http`module. `request` and `superagent` are great and easy to make remote requests

to install those module:

```
npm install request --save
var request = require('request');

npm install superagent --save
var request = require('superagent');
```

see more at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying. I have it working with `request`, I was wondering if there was a way to do it without it though and only through using Express.

Comment: Use node built-in `http` module  

[see sample code here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)