# Using Express to get geoCoding from google API

Tags: node.js, google-maps, express, https, geocoding

I am having difficulty getting my LatLon look up to work - I have read 
[Get Google Maps Geocoding JSON from Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929103/get-google-maps-geocoding-json-from-express) - but that just says use HTTP...and I have read the docs on http/https - but I'm still getting an error.

Here is my code - so calling myUrl/LatLon should give me the Google API response - or at least that is what I want...

```
const https = require('https');

router.get( '/LatLon', ( res ) => {console.log('Here getting https');
    const googleKey = '---';
    const address = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA';
    const options = new URL('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + googleKey);

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    req.write();
    req.end();
});
```

I get this error -

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type undefined
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:595:11)
at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I have tried about 4 variations on using "get" or "https"...

Answer (score 1):

I found node-geocoder - and it worked great...

Basically I did this, it is 'generalized code', non-functional; but you'll get the idea.
A bunch of checks and compares went into it so I am not hitting API's when I do not need to.

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
var options = {
  provider: process.env.GEOCODING_PROVIDER,
  httpAdapter: 'https',
  apiKey: process.env.GEOCODING_KEY,
  formatter: null
};
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);


collection.getExistingId( req.params.id, ( err, record ) => {

    const existingAddress = addresstoString(record.address);
    const newAddress = addresstoString(newRecord.address);

    if ( !compareAddresses(existingAddress,newAddress) ) {          

        geocoder.geocode(newAddress, function(err, geocode) {

            let coords = []; // mongoDB wants [Long,Lat]
                coords[0] = geocode[0].longitude;
                coords[1] = geocode[0].latitude;

            // set existingAddress.COORDINATES = coords
            // save the record

        });
    }

});
```